# AudioRecording not working in some devices

Tags: android, audio-recording, illegalstateexception, background-service, audiorecord

I am recording audio using android audiorecoder, but its is not working in some device like Huawei and oppo, I am recording audio for 5 second in background service. 
start recording function is:

```
private void startRecording(File file) {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
    }
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   // mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000);
    } else {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
    }
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("giftlist", "io problems while preparing [" +
                file.getAbsolutePath() + "]: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and stop recording function is

```
private void stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

this is the expection

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
```

it is giving illegal-stack exception. How to fix this issue? i want to run it in all devices

Comment: Have you checked runtime permissions to record audio?

Comment: If there are exceptions, please post the stack trace.

Comment: yes all permissions are set

Comment: The media recorder method needs to be called in a predefined sequence. If any of the methods will switch places, it will start throwing illegal state exception. You can search by "media recorder illegal state exception " and will get the result on google

Comment: can you please check the above code and let me know if there sequence correct or wrong. as it is working in Samsung devices